# How to automatically obtain the dom0's vm state?

Tags: xen, libvirt

The My server is `CentOS5.X`, the CCP has been installed, but the `python version 2.4`, `libvirt 0.7.x version`.
I from dom0 obtain the domU state
`Libvirt 0.7 virEventRunDefaultImpl provided (libvirt 0.8 only)` method

In addition to the round robin Now, there is no automatic callback state to dom0?

Thank's

Comment: It is hard to understand your English. Do you want to determine the domU state from dom0?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "xm list" command on Dom0 to check the state of virtual machines running on your Dom0. The output will show state like running,block,crash etc.
For details please refer http://linux.die.net/man/1/xm.